# How do I simplify $(1-\beta x)(-\beta x)^2 + \beta x(1-\beta x)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify the expression, $(1-\beta x)(-\beta x)^2 + \beta x(1-\beta x)^2$?

Thank you.

Comment: Expand it first, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since $uv^2+vu^2=uv(u+v)$, your sum is the case $u=1-v,\,v=\beta x$, giving $\beta x(1-\beta x)=\beta x-\beta^2x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Bring out the factor $1-\beta x,$ to get $$(1-\beta x)(\beta^2 x^2+\beta x-\beta^2x^2)=\beta x(1-\beta x).$$ You may multiply this out if you wish, but I consider this form to be the simplest, especially for computational purposes.

Answer (score 0):

$(1−)(−)^2+(1−)^2    $
$(^2^2 - ^3^3) + (1 - 2 + ^2^2) $
$(^2^2 - ^3^3) + ( - 2^2^2 + ^3^3) $
$^2^2 - ^3^3 +  - 2^2^2 + ^3^3 $
$^2^2  +  - 2^2^2$
$ - ^2^2$

Comment: You got the right answer, but your algebra is wrong $(-\beta x)^2$ = $\beta ^2 x^2$

Comment: Thank you for point it out. Went back and made some edits.